# Possible scores

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> A certain contest has three types of questions: part A, part B, and part C. There are 10 part A questions, 10 part B questions, and 5 part C questions. Each part A question is worth 5 points, each part B question is worth 6 points, and each part C question is worth 8 points. Not answering a question results in 2 points awarded for that question. Answering a question incorrectly results in 0 points for that question. How many scores from 0 to 150 are impossible to obtain?

I tried considering the possible "states" of the questions. Let $A_w$ represent the number of part $A$ questions answered wrongly, $A_u$ represent the number of part $A$ questions unanswered, and let $B_w, B_u, C_w,C_u$ be defined similarly. Let $1\leq x \leq 150.$ We want to consider the values of $x$ for which it is impossible to assign values to $A_w, A_u, B_w, B_u,C_w, C_u$ such that $0\leq A_w+A_u \leq 10, 0\leq B_w + B_u \leq 10, 0\leq C_w + C_u\leq 5$ so that $x-150 = -5A_w - 3A_u - 6B_w - 4B_u - 8C_w - 6C_u.$ We will list possibilities in the form $(C_w, C_u, B_w, B_u, A_w, A_u).$ The approach uses something similar to the greedy algorithm. Some cases are evidently impossible: 149, 148, 1. Others are definitely possible:

- $147 - (0,0,0,0,0,1)$
- $146 - (0,0,0,1,0,0)$
- $145 - (0,0,0,0,1,0)$
- $144 - (0,1,0,0,0,0)$
- $143 - (0,0,0,1,0,1)$
- $142 - (1,0,0,0,0,0)$
- $141 - (0,0,0,0,0,3)$
- $140 - (0,0,0,0,2,0)$
  etc.

It seems that there are many scores that are obtainable, but I'm not sure how to show this efficiently. I think the answer is $4$- the only unobtainable ones are $1,3,149,148$, but I'm not sure how to show this.
Also, since there are $25$ questions in total and you get $2$ points for an unanswered question, any score of the form $2k, 1\leq k\leq 25$ is valid. Also, any score of the form $5k, 1\leq k\leq 10$ is valid, and similarly any score of the form $8k, 1\leq k\leq 5, 6k 1\leq k\leq 10$ is valid. This gives that $36$ scores from $1-60$ are obtainable.

> Clarification: I made a typo in the original question. I should've said $10$ part $A$ questions and $5$ part $C$ questions instead of $5$ part $A$ questions and $10$ part $C$ questions.

Comment: If I read right, the maximum score is $165=5\cdot5+6\cdot10+8\cdot10$ [1, 3, 163, 164](https://tio.run/##RY7BCoMwEETv@Yocd2sr2mIRwS8JQaTaNopJyOagX58m2tI9LDOPYXbt5t9G32rrQqCWRg@ikMjWFoS4nispTxVmu75HXRZfUx@GqcUa5/nD2I09jeOKK83XhvE41LWJ52kB4c5SZkoZdWR@bE6MOv6ne0PeDwPM2YTMOqU9UDw2DpDedL1@jbD0a6zOSsQLIYbwAQ) are not obtainable.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I made a typo. Apologies.

Comment: Now I'm sorry that you have to read the solution, but otherwise the idea didn't come out of my mind, except as for writing it down. It's rather long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rephrase the problem a bit:

> If you have $10$ places for coins valued $5$, $10$ places for coins valued $6$, $5$ places for coins valued $8$ and can leave a place empty with value $0$ of fill it with a coin value $2$, what are impossible sums of values between the minimal and the maximal?

Proof outline: we reach a specific score starting from $5$ by adding $1$, proving we can do that, and by adding $-1$ starting from $150-3$, so the full interval is covered except the ends, that are considering directly.
In order to prove we can $+1$ we build a strategy considering number of having $5$s, $6$s if no $5$s, and $8$s if no both $6$s and $5$s, and almost similar way for $-1$ -- for $-1$ we consider $150-$score as target value, doing $+1$ on that value with coins $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$ and $8$

So, clearly, $0,2,4,5$ are achivable and $1,3$ are not, so let's start with $5$ and see if we can "add $1$".
I'll mean "exchange $\hbox{something}_1$ for $\hbox{something}_2$" in natural way: one gives $\hbox{something}_1$ and takes $\hbox{something}_2$ instead, I could say "replace by".

If we have some $5$s then we can exchange $5$ for $6$, obtaining $+1$.
If all $6$s places are full, we can exchange 4 $6$s for 3 $8$s if we have enuogh (3) places for $8$.
If we don't, this means we have at least 3 $8$s so we can exchange 3 $8$s for 5 $5$s (as we already don't have one $5$, if we had, we would $5\to 6$).
So now we have $5$s, all $6$s are full, we can't 4$\cdot6\to$3$\cdot 8$ as there's no 3 places for $8$ and we can't 3$\cdot8\to$5$\cdot 5$ as there are no 5 places for $5$, then minimal score for this is $150-2\cdot 8-4\cdot 5=114$.

So now we don't have $5$s.
If we have some $6$s we can exchange $6$ for $5+2$, obtaining $+1$ if we have a place for $2$ (we do, all the $5$'s places are empty). But in this case if we have 3 $2$s we exchange them to $6$ back immediately if we have a place for $6$. If not, we can 4$\cdot6\to$5$\cdot 5$, obtaining $+1$ as we don't have any $5$s.

So now we have neither $5$, nor $6$, nor 3$\cdot 8$ for $\to$5$\cdot5$, nor 2$\cdot 2$ for $\to 5$, nor $8+2$ to exchange for 2$\cdot 5$ so only 1 or 2 $8$s. We exchange $8$ for 4$\cdot2$ and then 2$\cdot2\to5$, obtaining $+1$.

I suppose, the reasoning is rigorous enough. )

Now remember $114$. Let's see the problem from the other end -- consider inverse problem -- we got 5 inverse points for failing A, 6 for failing B, 8 for failing C, 0 for a right answer, 3 for "don't know" A, 4 for "don't know" B, 6 for "don't know" C. The sum of inverse scores is exactly $150-\hbox{usual score}$.

Clearly $1$ and $2$ is unreachable, as we don't have such inverse coins, so we start with $3$. We can $+1$ by either:
Exchanging $3$ for $4$ or $4$ for $5$ or $5$ for $6$ or $3+4$ for $8$ or $8$ for 3$\cdot3$,
it's the hardest part, so bear with me)
If we can't exchange $3$ for $4$, but have $3$, this means all the $4$ are full (remember, $4$ is "don't know B (not answering B)") with either $6$s or $4$s, thus we have at least $40$, but we need $150-114=36$ to reach from the other end, so we're done here.
If we can't exchange $4$ for $5$ there's no place for $5$, thus we have $50$ and we're done. Similarly for $5\to 6$ we have $60$ (as $6$ we take only "fail B (wrong answer on B)").
If we can't $8\to$3$\cdot3$ but have $8$ (no places for 3$\cdot3$) we exchange 4$\cdot 3$ for 2$\cdot6$, if we can't it can be that 'B'-places are full and we have $40$ or we don't have 4$\cdot 3$ -- in this case if we don't have 3$\cdot 3$ either (but at least 8 'A' places are occupied, so at least 5$\cdot 6$+2$\cdot 3=36$) or we can 3$\cdot 3\to$2$\cdot 5$ to obtain $+1$.
If we can't $3+4\to 8$ it have to be either of: 5$\cdot 8$ are full so at least $40$, we don't have $3$ so can $4\to 5$ or we don't have $4$ so we can $3\to 4$ or we obviously don't have $4$s and $3$s.

And the case of 'A' places full have to be corrected: if all 'A' places full (with either "don't know" or "wrong answer") we can 5$\cdot 3\to$5$\cdot 3$, making 2 free places, or we don't have 5$\cdot 3$ thus the minimum is 6$\cdot 5+$4$\cdot 3=42$, not $50$ as mentioned above.
That completes the proof, as we can reach $114$ from both ends with $\pm 1$.
Answer: [1,3,150-1,150-2](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwEEX3OUWWM7UVbbFIIScJQaTaNopJyGShp08TS2lnMfAenz/jtvCy5tI6HyMJGgPISiFbBUh5PjZKHeoKix2u/9AmaJDpxVkf@N26jT2s55prw9cb42moE9mXeQHh7nJmyhn9yXzdnB11/Gf3hrIfBpiLCZnz2gSgdGwcIL/pe/McYenXVF3UiCdCjPEN).

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: This answer was based on an earlier version of the question.*

I don't think this would necessarily be an easy problem with different parameters. But with these numbers, something stands out: you can easily get a solid range of scores just with the A questions.

Namely,

- with zero 5's, you can get any even number from 0 to 10;
- with one 5, you can get any odd number from 5 to 13;
- with two 5's, you can get any even number from 10 to 16;
- with three five's, you can get any odd number from 15 to 19;

In particular, you can get any score from 4 to 17 just with part A.

Now, if you start looking at what scores you can get by gradually adding correct B and (then) C questions, the gaps between them are small:

- 0, 6, 12, ..., 54, 60, 68, 76, ..., 132, 140.

Since the increments are small, when you add to these a variable score on part A that can be anything from 4 to 17, there are no gaps left. Nothing is left out from 4 to 157.

Obviously, you can get a score of 2, but not 1 or 3. So the answer is that the only scores left out between 0 and 150 are 1 and 3.